# Writing Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, ant, properties

Could you tell me how I would write a regular expression for the string below in ant? I have a property called typeSplitFirstPart. I want to insert a couple of values after the property typeSplitFirstPart which can either be Product_A or Product_PD or Product_CD (see below).

```
CSDT_FLAG_PRODUCT_FF_FWUIDS=Product_A:*;Product_PD:*;Product_CD:*
```

Currently I have this, but it is not working.

```
   <replaceregexp file="x" flags="s" match="([^\.]*)\$\{typeSplitFirstPart:\*?\}([^\.]*)" replace="$HELLOEVERYONE\2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

These are pure regex pattern assuming * is any character but semicolon (`[^;]`)

First part is mandatory, at least one product is mandatory, and product can't be empty:

```
^([A-Z_]+)=(?:(Product_[A-Z]+):([^;]+);?)+
```

First part is mandatory, products are optional but not empty:

```
^([A-Z_]+)=(?:(Product_[A-Z]+):([^;]+);?)*
```

First part is mandatory, products are optional and they can be empty:

```
^([A-Z_]+)=(?:(Product_[A-Z]+):([^;]*);?)*
```

Just note that the group starting with `?:` is not returning anything for optimization.

Comment: Thanks. But i need to retrieve the ant property represented by typeSplitFirstPart which might be product A product CD etc. So i need to know how i would write this property variable in the regex code. usually to refer you say ${typeSplitFirstPart} however if i escape this using back slash still it doesnt work. if i just escape the $ with a backslash then it recognizes and gets the variable value but presents an error java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException. Would you know how this is solved?